# How to use Ionic SQLite to DUMP/export a specific TABLE?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, ionic-framework

On my Ionic application, I have some tables to store user custom stuff. These tables stores personal preferences and other user customizations on the app. I want to give the users the possibility to export this preferences to backup.

I use the **SQLitePorter** to import a SQL file into my app, but it doesn't have a feature to export a TABLE or a junction of tables for the relation, only the entire DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sqlite3 binary provides a .dump command.  If you cannot use that, then you you need query the data and write it out in a suitable format.